Возвращает undefined, но в console.log выводит верно
При вызове функции через return возвращается undefined, но через console.log все данные верны. Как исправить?
module.exports.find_info = () => {
    db.all("SELECT * FROM test", (err, rows) => {
        if (err) { return err; }
        return rows;
    });
}


Вот эта функция find_info = () => {} ничего никуда не возвращает, а return rows, по всей видимости, возвращается "вникуда"

Возможный дубликат вопроса: Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания
